# Using numpy stride-tricks to operate on two different-sized moving windows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am processing a 1-dimensional array of data. I am looking for a greater than expected variance within a 7 item window, but would then need to correct values within a larger, 20 item window.

I'm using python and NumPy to accomplish the task.  I started using numpy stride_tricks to create a moving window through the original array.  Stride_tricks seemed the fastest way computationally to find the higher variance in the smaller windows.  I get stuck when attempting to expand the window to correct the data.

Here's my current code:

```
with open('Sather-line-352-original.txt') as f:
   array = np.array(map(int, f))

# shape defines the dimensions of the new temp array.
# strides define memory-based coordinates of original array items.
def pystride(array,frame_length,strided_items):
   num_frames = 1 + ((len(array) - frame_length)/ strided_items)
   row_stride = array.itemsize * strided_items
   col_stride = array.itemsize

   a_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
      array,
      shape=(num_frames, frame_length),
      strides=(row_stride, col_stride)
   )
   return a_strided

def find_max_min(array):
   max_diff = 120

   for sub in pystride(array,frame_length=7,strided_items=2):
      max_val = max(sub)
      min_val = min(sub)
      if abs(max_val - min_val) >= max_diff:
         # assign 'pointers' in original array indicating where large diffs are found.
         sub[0] = int('{:<05}'.format(sub[0]))

find_max_min(array)
```

Particularly, is there a way to determine where the as_strided sub-array is in the original array?  I've been modifying the data by appending 000 at the end of an integer value to act as a makeshift pointer, but that seems like a hack at best.  Could I temporarily resize the sub-array for modification, and then resize back to the smaller window to continue scanning?

Here is a snippet of the array:
93,94,91,90,93,85,79,60,50,48,54,58,47,49,63,91,134,165,184,178,161,161,154,151,140,129,113,87,51,23,14,17,33,59,91,127,154,165,165,160,163

An example of data that requires correction occurs when the values fall from 140 to 14 within 7 values.  Finding this means that everything from 23 to 33 will need to be bumped up between 51 and 59.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the code you have written so far?

Comment: `stride_tricks` can be dangerous if you don't get the shape right, and start accessing values outside the data buffer.  Don't try to fudge it,

Comment: I assume you are using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,strides=(8,8),shape=(41-6,7))`, where the shape was chosen to not fall off the end.  The resulting 2d array will be useful if you can do whole array operations on it, e.g. `mean` or `sum` by axis.  But it's hard to make sense of what else you are trying to do.  But once you start iterating on the windows to do special tests, you loose most of the `strided` speed advantage.

Comment: I've updated the original post to add current code.

Comment: If not using stride_tricks, would you index the array or add an iterator?